# Deploying All Components of Managed Package from one Org to Another Org

Tags: managed-package

I have added a Named Credential component into My Managed Package List and not able to delete it from the Managed Package list or within the Organization. I have raised a case to delete those components from Managed Package but My team is planning to deploy all the components into a new org and create a new managed Package. May I know how can we deploy all those components without any connection b/w the Orgs? How long it takes and what needs to be tested?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a tool like VS Code or even just use [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx) directly. You can use the Package Retrieve to get the contents of the package, then deploy it to the new org. Here's DX:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "Managed Package Name" -u sourceOrg
```

And then:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/ -u destOrg
```

Comment: +1, and also: this is a great opportunity to make the critical move to source-based development of this managed package.